# File handling and counting of occurrence of a string in files

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Occurrences( inputFileNames, words, outputFileName )
```

For each file in the list `inputFileNames`, output to
a file called `outputFileName` the name of the input
file and for each word in the list `words`, the number of
occurrences that individual word; if any of the input
files cannot be read, issue a suitable error message
and skip that file. For added fun, do it without using
the `.count()` built-in function.

`Occurrences( ["sample1.txt","sample2.txt","sample3.txt"],
 ["why","you","fate","among"], "out.txt")`

`out.txt` then contains:

`File Name: why you fate among
sample1.txt 3 0 0 0
sample2.txt 2 2 1 1
sample3.txt 0 3 0 0`

And what I've got so far is

```
def Occurrences(inputFileNames,words,outputFileName):
    output = open(outputFileName,"a")

    try:
        for file in inputFileNames:
            opned = open(file,"r")
            print(opned)
            counters = [0 for file in range (len(words))]
            index = 0
            for i in words:
                for line in opned:
                    if i in line:
                        print("WORD",i,"LINE",line)
                        counters[index] += 1
                index +=1
            print(counters)

    except IOError:
        file.close()
        print("*** Occurrences: File handle Error")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also definitely recommend using the count method. From your example, I can not really see where you try to write results to your output file, so I will explain a possible implementation.

```
def occurrences(inputFileNames, words, outputFileName):
    wordCount = {}
    # This dictionary will hold our wordCount and be used for construnction of the output file

    for file in inputFileNames:
        # Iterate over the files
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as infile:
                content = infile.read().strip().split(" ")
            # Declare entry to wordCount for file only if no IOError is raised
            wordCount[file] = [0 for j in range(len(words))]
            for i in  range(len(words)):
                # Instead of iterating over the contents manually, split them and use the count method
                wordCount[file][i] = str(content.count(words[i]))
        except IOError:
            print("The file {} could not be read.".format(file))

    with open(outputFileName, 'w+') as outfile:
        # Iterate over the wordCount dict and write the output
        for i in wordCount.keys():
            outfile.write(i+" "+" ".join(wordCount[i])+"\n")
occurrences(["book.txt"], ["Alice", "hole", "Rabbit"], "occ.txt")
```

occ.txt then contains:

```
book.txt 155 0 26
```

To do this without the count method, one possible way would be to iterate over the content list element by element and to increment the count if the word matches the element.

```
for i in  range(len(words)):
    count = 0
    for word in content:
        if words[i] == word:
            count += 1
    wordCount[file][i] = str(count)
```

Comment: I appreciate that solution but is there a way it could be implemented without count as its an optional challenge and id like to know how it should be done

Comment: I added an example without the count method.